# Does java.net.HttpUrlConnection always throw IOException if there is an error status return by Server?

Tags: java, exception, httpurlconnection, http-status-codes

I am using **java.net.HttpUrlConnection** to make Http requests to my Server. I realized that if the Server return an error status (400 for example). HttpUrlConnection will throw an IOException corresponding to the error status.

My question is:  **Does HttpUrlConnection always throw an IOException if the server return an error status (4xx, 5xx)?**

I take a look at [HttpUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) API description but I couldn't answer my question.

**Updated: Please see my test:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=___fake_token";
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
        
        conn.getResponseCode();
        conn.getInputStream();
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // Print IOException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=abc

        // If I commented conn.getResponseCode() -> The same IOException
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. This behavior occurs if the following conditions are true: The Web site that you try to view uses Integrated Windows authentication. The application pool for the Web site recycles during the authentication process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not if you check `getResponseCode()` before `getInputStream()` and the problem is an HTTP return code rather than a connect error.

Comment: I included a test. I call getResponseCode before getInputStream and I got IOException. Please see my example!

Comment: @Loc The exception is thrown by `getInputStream()` in both cases. Your new example is futile because you ignored the result of `getResponseCode()`. If you had programmed it properly, as I assumed, you would have seen that the value was 401 and not attempted to call `getInputStream()` at all.

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case of codes beyond 400 you need to call `HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream()` instead of `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()`. Java 11 implementation:

```
public InputStream getErrorStream() {
    if (this.connected && this.responseCode >= 400) {
        if (this.errorStream != null) {
            return this.errorStream;
        }
        if (this.inputStream != null) {
            return this.inputStream;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```